# Run reindexall via cron

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, reindex

Hi I'm trying to run the indexer for a website using the cron.  I have the timing set correctly but the command is not working, probably something simple but any ideas people?

/opt/plesk/php/5.5/php -f /var/www/vhosts/aropec.co.uk/shell/indexer.php reindexall

Comment: what happen if you execute this line in your Terminal?

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: did you execute the whole line? I meant `/opt/plesk/php/5.5/php -f /var/www/vhosts/aropec.co.uk/shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: /opt/plesk/php/5.5/php: No such file or directory

Comment: you use the a wrong php path. To finde the correct path execute in your Terminal `which php`

Comment: ah ha we are getting somewhere.  It now seems to recognise the php directory but I now get the error could not open input file: /var/www etc etc.

Comment: i don't know your filesystem, but you can try this command to finde the correct filepath `find /var/www -name indexer.php`. I assume, that the files are locaten in `/var/www`

Comment: The location is correct for the indexer.php file it just states it can't open it.  Could be down to user rights?

Comment: Sorted it, must have been something wrong with the indexer.php file.  Replaced it with the backup and is now working thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you can do it by below script in your php file

```
$indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 

foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {

      $process->reindexEverything();

}
```

Comment: So I need to call up a php file I can't just do it directly?